# How to create model for different databases?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I just started learning ROR. And came across this DOUBT.
I have defined multiple databases in my **database.yml** file like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: mydb1
  username: root
  password: root
  host: localhost

custom:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: true
  database: customdb
  username: root
  password: root
  host: localhost
```

Now if I create a model using `rails generate model MyModel`, it will generate a migration to create table - `my_models` in `mydb1`.

My question is **"How can I create/specify a model, that to create a table under customdb?"**

Do I need to change my rails environment or is there any other way? I am just curious. I can do this manually by creating a table in `customdb` and creating a model without migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to specify environment in rails g command, then It will create a table automatically in customdb database

```
RAILS_ENV=custom rails generate model MyModel
```

Comment: Do i need to have separate environment like development,production and test.?
cz it is showing 
`config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true
`

Comment: From referring to error, i have set `config.eager_load` to `false` in both development & test fiels and `true` in production file.

But still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand why you would like to generate model for specific db.

All you have to do is generate standart model and add this line `establish_connection :custom` to it. This model should work with your custom db, you can run migrations as usual after adding `establish_connection`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a matter of environment.

[This is my pattern](https://gist.github.com/masciugo/a043df2a0f308f96be15). In few words I created an abstract model, (between AR and your other-db models, where I specify this fact. All models derived from it point to the other db (*public_database* in my gist). Connections parameters are stored in an extra .yml file (*config/database_public.yml*)

Running rake tasks on multiple databases is harder but, in the second part of the gist, I found a way to create tasks which operate on both databases but separately.